# Converting Spark Dataset into JSON

Tags: json, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a spark dataset into JSON. I tried .toJSON()  method but its not much of a help.

I have a dataset which looks like this

```
|          ord_status|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|             Fallout| 3374|
|         Flowthrough|12083|
|         In-Progress| 3804|
```

I am trying to convert to it to a JSON like this:

```
"overallCounts": {

        "flowthrough": 2148,
        "fallout": 4233,
        "inprogress": 1300
    }
```

My question is that is there any way through which we can parse column values side by side and show them as JSON.

Update: I converted dataset in given json format by converting it into a list and then parsing each value and putting it into a string. Although that's lot of manual work. Are there any built in methods which can convert datasets into such json format?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below solution. Dataset has to iterate using `mapPartitions` then generate the final string which contains the only JSON elements.

```
val list = List(("Fallout",3374), ("Flowthrough", 12083), ("In-Progress", 3804))
val ds = list.toDS()

ds.show
val rows = ds.mapPartitions(itr => {
      val string =
        s"""
          |"%s" : %d
          |""".stripMargin
      val pairs = itr.map(ele => string.format(ele._1, ele._2)).mkString
      Iterator(pairs)
    })

val text = rows.collect().mkString

val finalJson = """
        |"overallCounts": {
        |        %s
        |    }
        |""".stripMargin

println(finalJson.format(text))
```